# how to use select statement with form data in where condition to insert data into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a code to insert data in mysql which is inserting multiple rows to the database from form successfully. but i want to use a select statement which will fetch data from other table  using where condition. 
here is my post code.

```
<?php
include('mysql.php');
require("dbconn.php");

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $stockid = $_POST["series"];
        $desc = $_POST["season"];
        //$price = $row['price']; - remove
        foreach($stockid as $a => $B)
        {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 0_stock_master (stock_id, description) VALUES ('$stockid[$a]','$desc[$a]')");
} 
}
?>
```

now i want to use this code to fetch data and insert in to above query for all rows....

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM 0_stock_category where category_id = '".$_POST["series"]."'", $con);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result9))
    {
     $code = $row['description'];
    }
```

Please tell me how to use above code how to put this code in my post data......
my insert statement may look like this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 0_stock_master (stock_id, description, code) VALUES ('$stockid[$a]','$desc[$a]','$code[$a]')");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd highly recommend you stop using `mysql_*` functions — these are deprecated and really not secure. Start learning PDO and its prepared statements, this will help you a lot.
But anyway, you might want to do the following:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 0_stock_master (stock_id, description, code) VALUES ('$stockid[$a]', '$desc[$a]', (SELECT description from 0_stock_category WHERE category_id = '".$_POST['series']."'))");
```

Comment: its working thank you very much. just a single edit in your code is i use `stockid[$a]` instead of `$_POST['series']`